# Firebase and offline Cordova: How to access user local datas when offline

Tags: cordova, firebase, firebase-authentication, offline

I'm using Firebase on my Cordova app and everything seems to work fine offline except the authentication part.

Here is the scenario:
- The user runs the app when online, logs in, everything's fine. His name appears, he's connected.
- Later he runs the app when offline and appears disconnected

But I'd like to access those user datas even when he's offline (So I can still dispay his name and other datas). How can I do that ?
Apparently Firebase stores the datas under a localStorage key with an hash. So I can't do anything with that.

Also `firebase.auth().currentUser` returns null

Any help would be appreciated :)

Thanks a lot

Comment: Firebase Auth should persist offline. If you sign in a user via Firebase Auth and cache the binary js and then relaunch the app in offline mode, onAuthStateChanged listener should trigger that the user is logged in and the currentUser should be populated.

Comment: Oh you're sure about that ?...It doesn't seem to be the case. Thanks for your answer

Comment: I tested this in the past in a browser environment. The same should be true for Cordova. Please test it and let me know if you encounter a different behavior.

Comment: I'll give it a look this week-end and come back at you. Thanks again

Comment: Yes, it does work in the browser, of course. But the browser is not Cordova. Is there any update on whether this works as one would expect in Cordova?

Comment: Yeah it works fine